# Why can’t I render data from this object ? How can I?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component "Form". I also have some data that I get from my mongoDB DB, and whose state `(myData)` I dispatch.

So in the Form component, I have a `mapstatetoprops` function to convert myData to props. myData is an object.

I want to use the data from the myData object and display some of the properties of that object in the return function of the component.

When I type this in the render method :

```
const  {myData}  = this.props;

console.log(myData);
```

I can see my object and its content in the console, the way i want.

{myData} looks like this :

```
{ title: "mytitle", comments: [{comment: "qqq", vote: 1}, {comment: "www", vote: 2}]}
```

However, for some reason I don't understand, I cannot use `{myData}` in the return method of the component. When I do, I get the following error message :

> Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   `createFragment(object)` from the React add-ons

I understood you cannot use objects in the return. But it's an object that I have, not an Array.

I expected I could write this in my `return : {myData.title}` to see the title when my component renders.

The following returns the error message : `myData is undefined`

```
render(){

  const  {myData}  = this.props;

  console.log(myData);

  return(

  <div>{myData.title}</div>

  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the proper value in `console`, It looks like when first time it is rendering, it didn't find the `myData` inside `props` values, You have to keep in mind that the output you see in the `console` is computed at the moment you **expand** the properties, not at the moment `console.log` is called. In fact, the little `i` icon next to `Object` tells you that.

So just put a check on that, it should work, like this:

```
render(){
    const  {myData}  = this.props;
    console.log(myData);
    return(
       <div> Hello {myData && myData.title} </div>
    )
}
```

Run this in `browser console`, and expand the `object`, it will show the updated values not the initial values:

```
obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5, arr: []}; 
console.log(obj);
obj.a = 5;
```

Comment: ok, that works :) 

You're right when you say that it didn't find the myData inside props values. The console log returns 'undefined', then '[HMR] connected' then only the object.

Can you elaborate on : _is computed at the moment you expand the properties, not at the moment console.log is called_

I don't understand that. Or do you have a link ?

Comment: it means that let say you have an `object a` with some values, and you do `console.log(a)`, after that u did some changes in a, in `console` you will see the updated `a` values not the original one, even if you used `console.log` before making the changes in `a`. Means values will always be computed at run time when you expand the `object`, it will print the updated values of `a`.

Comment: To avoid this, and code in a cleaner way, does that mean I am supposed to connect my 'myData' state in the parent component instead of the component where I use myData ?

Comment: sorry, don't have much idea about `redux` i am using `flux` architecture, not able to help you in that :)

Comment: ok, never mind. I'll try this and see what's the result like. Thank you for your kind help !